# How can I use perf to collect performance metrics for a python program?

Tags: python, perf, ubuntu-20.04

To cut to the chase, I want to view performance stats using perf from linux-tools for an object detection program that is written in python. I am looking for stats like execution time, CPI, and MIPS. I am working in Ubuntu 20.04. I tried using "perf stat" and "perf record" while calling the file in the same line in the terminal, but something is wrong.

I can run the python file just fine by itself and I get the output I am expecting. But when I add perf stat in front of the python call, it says that one of the libraries is missing and exits the program. To add insult to injury, perf still shows performance metrics on exit but its obvious that the file did not run properly because there is no output.

The line I am running is

```
sudo perf stat python3 object_detection_sample_ssd.py -i /home/peter/Desktop/test/000000079529.jpg -m /home/peter/Desktop/frozen/ssdlite/frozen_inference_graph.xml -d MYRIAD
```

The error I am getting is

```
File "object_detection_sample_ssd.py", line 21, in <module>
        import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I definitely have this module installed because otherwise I wouldn't get an output in the first place. If anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried without using sudo.